# toml decoding - struct is empty

Tags: go

Please consider this code https://play.golang.org/p/QCU-deS8rwu

I've this  toml file,

```
[cameras]

    [cam7]
    url = "http://creds:creds@192.168.1.112/tmpfs/auto.jpg"
    name = "cam7"

    [cam3]
    url = "http://creds:creds@192.168.1.90/tmpfs/auto.jpg"
    name = "cam3"
```

While parsing it, I see the MetaData gets populated, but my struct seems empty:

`config: main.tomlConfig{cameras:[]main.camera(nil)}`

```
$ go run parsetoml.go 
tomlMetaData type: toml.MetaData
tomlMetaData {map[cam3:[map[name:cam3 url:http://creds:creds@192.168.1.90/tmpfs/auto.jpg]] cam7:[map[name:cam7 url:http://creds:creds@192.168.1.112/tmpfs/auto.jpg]] cameras:map[]] map[cam3:ArrayHash cam3.name:String cam3.url:String cam7:ArrayHash cam7.name:String cam7.url:String cameras:Hash] [[cameras] [cam7] [cam7 url] [cam7 name] [cam3] [cam3 url] [cam3 name]] map[] []}
config: main.tomlConfig{cameras:[]main.camera(nil)} // < -- this
---
--- <--??
```

Please show the correct way to parse this toml..

Comment: Trying https://play.golang.org/p/KC6bFRJzBWb, gives `2009/11/10 23:00:00 toml: cannot load TOML value of type map[string]interface {} into a Go slice`

Comment: You must put all relevant code directly into the question.